# How to remove single quotes from imported csv file into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv, single-quotes

I export a list into a csv file as:

```
file = open('all_states.csv', 'w+', newline='')

# writing the data into the file
with file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(all_states)
```

And from another script I import the csv file as:

```
with open('all_states.csv') as file:

    reader = csv.reader(file)

    states = list(reader)

file.close()
```

The original data that was exported was:

```
exp_data = [
    [[0], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [0, 0, 1]], 
    [[0], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [-1, 0, 0]], 
    [[0], [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [0, -1, 0]]
]
```

But when I imported I get some single quotes that I'd like to remove.

```
impo_data = [
    ['[0]', '[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]', '[0, 0, 1]'], 
    ['[0]', '[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]', '[-1, 0, 0]'], 
    ['[0]', '[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]', '[0, -1, 0]']
]
```

How can I remove the quotes when exporting or once imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your CSV file is read as a string, while you want to process it as if it is not. Your items look like they are all JSON, so just run them through `json.loads`.

```
states = [[json.loads(item) for item in row] for row in reader]
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, quotations are fine with csv format. But if you want to remove the quotes, you can try the following. While importing the csv file, define the [quotechar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
csv.reader(inp_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
```